# JsonIgnore dynamically If it is nested?

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have hibernate models like following:

Ticket Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ticket")
public class TicketModel {
    private BigInteger id;
    private UserModel user;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqTicket", sequenceName = "ticket_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqTicket")
    public BigInteger getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigInteger id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public UserModel getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserModel user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

User Model:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    public class UserModel {
        private BigInteger id;
        private String name;
        private CompanyModel company;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqUser", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqUser")
        public BigInteger getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(BigInteger id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        public CompanyModel getUser() {
            return company;
        }

        public void setUser(CompanyModel company) {
            this.company = company;
        }
    }
```

Company Model:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "company")
    public class UserModel {
        private BigInteger id;
        private String name;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqCompany", sequenceName = "company_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqCompany")
        public BigInteger getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(BigInteger id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Basic
        @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

Now, what i want to do is json ignoring user's company in my rest controller if I am returning ticket object. But if I am returning User object I dont want to ignore company relation.

For example:
in ticket controller's return it should be a json like :

```
{
  "id":1,
  "user":{
     "id":3,
     "name":"something"
   }
}
```

but in user controller's return it should be like:

```
{
  "id":3,
  "name":"something",
  "company":{
     "id":5,
     "name":"something else"
   }
}
```

So shortly, I want to ignore relations if it is in second dimension.
Is that possible?

Comment: Use Jackson's [JsonView](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation). If you're using Spring Data Rest, use [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections).

Comment: They don't meet my expectation. I think I should write a custom serializer.